# How create PDF/A file from HTML using iTextSharp

Tags: html, itext, pdfa

I want to create PDF/A from HTML using iTextsharp, but is having a hard time creating something that validateds to PDF/. This is the code that I use to test the functionality. What needs to be changed to get what I want?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create stylesheet (used to change font from default Helvetica in order to embed font in PDF/A)
        var styles = new StyleSheet();
        var fontPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\fonts\\verdana.ttf";
        FontFactory.Register(fontPath);
        styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "Verdana");


        var pdFdocument = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        const string strPdFpath = @"MyPDF.pdf-PDFX1A2001";
        var sr = new StringReader("<html><head></head><body><h1>Dette er en HTML-fil</h1><p>Dette er litt tekst i html-fila</p><br /><p>Dette er enda ett avsnitt. iTextSharp ser ut til å fungere greit...</p></body></html>");

        var htmlParser = new HTMLWorker(pdFdocument, null, styles);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdFdocument, new FileStream(strPdFpath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
        writer.PDFXConformance = PdfWriter.PDFX1A2001;
        pdFdocument.Open();
        htmlParser.Parse(sr);
        pdFdocument.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Your code of course. You need to explain **what is what you want** and what you're **getting that differs from what you want** and **what you did to get there**. Then we can talk about finer, more detailed changes.

Comment: In plain text; I want a valid pdf/a file! The PdfWriter provides three possible PDFXConformance options (PDFX1A2001, PDFX32002 and PDFXNONE), and non of the resulting PDF-files validates correctly.

Answer (score 3):

`PDFX1A2001` requires a version 1.3 PDF or less but setting the `PDFXConformance` property alone doesn't do this, you must manually do it:

```
writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_3);
```

Additionally, you also need to call `CreateXmpMetadata()` to "apply" the metadata.

```
writer.CreateXmpMetadata();
```

[Most](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8719794/231316) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2701332/231316) seem to do it just before closing the document but I don't know if this is a requirement.