# C#: I want to delete soe pages of existing PDF/A-2u Document and store it

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfa

I'm looking for a lib that gives me the possibility to delete some pages of an existing pdf and store it in PDF/A-2u Format.

The source PDF is already in this Format. I tried a lib of opentext. There it worked but the resulting PDF-Format is not PDF/A after the necessary changes. I wasn't able to store it in the original Format.

Can you give me some hints how to delete single pages of an existing PDF/A File?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364258/how-to-programmaticaly-construct-pdfs-with-pdf-a-format

Comment: *"I'm looking for a lib"* - library recommendation should be asked for on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).